# Android onReceiver() method not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms

I want my application to receive messages from a particular sender into my application through the BroadcastReceiver, unfortunately its not working and not throwing any error, 
Below is the code for the BroadcastReceiver:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Get Bundle object contained in the SMS intent passed in
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[]smsm=null;
        String sms_str = "";
        if (bundle != null) {
            // Get the SMS message
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            smsm = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < smsm.length; i++) {
                smsm[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                sms_str += "Sent From: " + smsm[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                sms_str += "\r\nMessage: ";
                sms_str += smsm[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                sms_str += "\r\n";
            }
            Log.d("TAG", sms_str);

            // Start Application's  MainActivty activity
            Intent smsIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            smsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            smsIntent.putExtra("sms_str", sms_str);
            context.startActivity(smsIntent);
        }
    }
```

In the Main Activity, I have this code to fetch the intent:

```
// Get intent object sent from the SMSBroadcastReceiver
        Intent sms_intent = getIntent();
        Bundle b = sms_intent.getExtras();
        if (b != null) {
            // Display SMS in the TextView
            txtViewSMS.setText(b.getString("sms_str"));
        }
```

My manifest file has:

```
<!-- Declare SMS Broadcast receiver -->
        <receiver android:name=".SMSBReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Kindly assist.
Much thanks

Comment: Do you get any error, if so please edit the question with logcat output

Comment: Can you please share what error it is throwing?

Comment: Hello, I dont get any error, @Mike, Im testing on Android 4.1.1 and my target SDK is 23

Comment: thanks, caught the culprit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have this permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

Also if receiver class name is `SMSBroadcastReceiver` then this name must be used in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter android:priority="999">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```